# Android save and retrieve date on Parse.com using Android date picker

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, datepicker, android-datepicker

EDIT: I now get the date by using the following code and I want to get the chosen date into a Parse date column (the String date variable):

```
private void setDateTimeField() {
    deadlineDateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            deadlineDateEditText.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            //get string version of date
            date = dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime());
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

My question is how do I add this to a Date column in Parse without the time? I have not come across any examples for Android yet. I am also concerned about the format that Parse requires for date types.

When I try to input the date with the following code I get `parse android expected date but got String`. Code:

```
public void addModuleDeadline()
{
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Module");
    query.whereEqualTo("moduleCode", moduleDeadlineSpinnerText);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null)
            {
                ParseObject deadlineObject = new ParseObject("ModuleDeadlines");
                deadlineObject.put("moduleCode", moduleDeadlineSpinnerText);
                deadlineObject.put("createdBy", currentUser);
                deadlineObject.put("deadlineTitle", deadlineTitleText);
                deadlineObject.put("deadline", date);
                deadlineObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error adding deadline: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deadline added to '" + moduleDeadlineSpinnerText + "'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There was an issue adding the deadline", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As I understand you can use `object.getDate("column name")` to get the date from Parse.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this by simply changing `deadlineObject.put("deadline", date);` to `deadlineObject.put("deadline", newDate.getTime());` which passes the date object rather then the string.

Hope this helps anyone else!